# Google Drive folder access information

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-chrome-devtools, bots, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm not very experienced with developing app/tools, but I really want to develop (if practically possible) a tool that would notify the owner of the Google Drive folder of the information related to someone else accessing the folder (assuming that the folder is shared with that someone) such as, Access Date/Time, Accessed By etc. In my opinion, this would only be done if the user/owner has the tool/app opened/switched on.

I was reading the Google Drive API but couldn't find anything useful on this.

I'd like to know how to get started with this project, if this is even possible? I'm not very experienced but I want to learn as I grow.

Comment: Users need to install Google drive chrome extension in order for API to work.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how this adds to this discussion, let's assume that this potential app/tool requires users to install Google Drive chrome extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend going though the Google Drive API.  When set up correctly [Changes.watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/watch) will notify you when ever a file has been changed the trick for you will then be to notify your user.

Alternative would be to just check the file every now and then and see if it had been changed using file.get.  However this is probably over kill depending upon how soon after the change you want to know about it.

I am not an android dev so cant help you much more then that.   Your question is rather broad so once you start working with it if you have any issues getting it working I recommend you ask a new question directly related to those issues.   Welcome to stack

Comment: Thank You for the start! But, would the Changes.watch notify me when a file is viewed as well? or only if it has been changed?

Comment: I dont think so looks like only modified and deleted https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes#resource  If you have the user authenticated then the second option would work because file.get has a last viewed by me date.   There doesn't look like there is a way to see the last time it was viewed by someone you have shared the file with if that's what you are after.    It takes a while to learn to read googles documentation but all the info is there.